# How's this optimization problem simplified?

Tags: optimization, quadratics

I encountered this optimization problem:  $$\min_S\sum_{i,j}\left [ -\sum_l w_lK_l(c_i,c_j)+\gamma (LL^T)_{ij} \right ]S_{ij}+\beta \left \| S \right \|_F^2$$
$$s.t \sum_jS_{ij}=1, S_{ij}\geq 0 \, \forall (i,j)$$
where $S$ is a matrix (each row is independant), the proposed approach to solve the problem is to parallel the solution by solving each row ( $s_1,...,s_N$) independently. The problem was then simplified to $N$ independant quadratic subproblems: 
$$\min_{s_i}\frac{1}{2}\|s_i-v_i\|_2^2 $$
$$s.t \,\,s_i^T1=1 \,,(s_i)_j\geq 0 \, \forall j $$
where $v_i$ (a $N$-length vector) defined as: 
$$(v_i)_j = -\frac{1}{2\beta}(\gamma (LL^T)_{ij}-\sum_l w_lK_l(c_i,c_j)) $$
The equivalence between the first and second equations remains unclear to me, is it a simple mathematical calculation that I miss or some kind of "trick" I can't see ?

Comment: There has to be some $S$-terms missing in the objective. As it is now, the problem is trivial to solve as the first term with sums doesn't depend on $S$

Comment: @JohanLöfberg, you're right, I forgot an S term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You objective can (after dividing with $\beta$) be written as $\sum_i -2s_i v_i^T + \left\| s_i\right\|^2$, which you can complete the squares on to $\sum_i \left\| s_i-v_i \right\|^2 -v_iv_i^T$. The constraints are not coupled between rows of $S$, hence you can solve $N$ problems.

Comment: doesn't this lead us to $\min_{s_i}\|s_i-v_i\|_2^2 $ why is there $\frac{1}{2}$ in the simplified objective function ?

Comment: The factor 1/2 is completely arbitrary. You can multiply with $\pi$ if you want to. It is just very common to have 1/2 before quadratics

Comment: What if we add another term to the objective quadratic term ($\|m_i-m_j\|_2^2$), the problem becomes:$$\min_S\sum_{i,j}\left [ -\sum_l w_lK_l(c_i,c_j)+\gamma (LL^T)_{ij}+\|m_i-m_j\|_2^2 \right ]S_{ij}+\beta \left \| S \right \|_F^2$$  can we still solve it the same way ? and we just  define$v_i$ as $$(v_i)_j = -\frac{1}{2\beta}(\gamma (LL^T)_{ij}-\sum_l w_lK_l(c_i,c_j)+\|m_i-m_j\|_2^2 ) $$

Comment: $m = 0$ is trivially optimal as $m$ doesn't appear in any constraint

Comment: I don't get you, why $m= 0$ ? it represents something and $S$ depends of it. The other terms don't appear in constraints too and S was solved  in regards to them.

PS: please don't get bored of my questions, I am totally new to the field.

Comment: The best you can do is to set $m_i = m_j = 0$. You cannot get any lower than $||m_i-m_j|| =0$. You have not said anywhere that $S$ is a function of $m$ or $m$ being a function of $S$.